# VFP sql prepass

Tags: sql, t-sql, visual-foxpro, pass-through

I have no idea what the official name for it is so maybe that's why i can't find anything online.
Basically, when you use sql in vfp it does an initial pass through (sometimes 2?) without moving the record cursor or saving the results.
Unfortunately I have sub routines in my sql that run and change things during that initial pass.

Why am i using subroutines in sql queries? Because vfp doesn't support referencing outside a subquery within the select items (once again i don't know the official name).

Example: `select id, (select detail.name from detail where master.id == detail.id) name from master`

This does work though: `select id, getname(id) from master`

where `getname()` is a sub routine containing the sql from the first example.

You could also use a join, but the above is just an example and a join does not work in my case.

Is there any way to deal with initial pass throughs? Does vfp create a boolean like `firstpass` or something? I suppose i could add a count to my subroutine, but that seems messier than it already is.

Alternatively can someone explain or link me an explanation to vfp's initial pass? I believe it was only doing one initial pass before but now it's doing two after changing some code.

Edit: ok, i was wrong. The above example does work. What doesn't work is the following:
`SELECT d2.id, (SELECT TOP 1 d1.lname l FROM dpadd d1 WHERE d1.id== d2.id ORDER BY l) FROM dpadd d2`
It gives me a "SQL: Queries of this type are not supported" error.
Strangely it works if i do the following:
`SELECT d2.id, (SELECT COUNT(d1.lname) FROM dpadd d1 WHERE d1.id == d2.id) FROM dpadd d2`

About the subroutines, they are methods of my form. The databases are local .dbf files. I'm not interacting with any servers, just running straight sql commands with `into cursor` clauses and then generating reports (usually).

I'll post back in a few minutes with an actually useful select statement that "is not supported". I'm sure you've noticed the `top 1` example is completely useless.

Comment: Clarification... Is the GetName() a function in the local VFP side? or is it a stored procedure in the SQL-Server you are connecting TO.  Also, could you show what you are trying to actually do?  VFP Deos support complex sub-query callss to SQL Server, even parameterized queries using local variables without changing the SQL string to be executed via SQLPrepare() or SQLExec().

Answer (score 0):

It appears that TOP is not permitted in projections. For that example, you can instead do this:

```
SELECT d2.id, (SELECT MAX(d1.lname) l FROM dpadd d1 WHERE d1.id== d2.id) FROM dpadd d2
```

What else is giving you a problem?

Tamar